# How to change a TextView's text by pressing a Button

Tags: android, button, textview

I want to change the of a `TextView` by pressing a `Button`, but don't understand how to do it properly.

This is part of my layout:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change text!" />
```

And this is my activity:

```
public class Click extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                // ???
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What should I put inside `onClick()` method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Find the textview by id
2. Change the text by invoking `yourTextView.setText("New text");`

Refer [`findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) and [`setText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) methods.

Comment: One important thing: the field is updated only when you get out from the onClick block, you cannot update the same field twice.

Answer (score 15):

According to:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

```
TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
view.setText("Do whatever");
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Click extends Activity {
int i=0;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter) 
        mTextView.setText("hello "+i);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
              i=i+1;  
              mTextView.setText("hello "+i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this serve your need

Comment: I tried this,and i modify something like this `mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(i));`, and it's worked. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) v;
tv.setText("My new text");
```

**Edit:**
Here is your handler:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TextView tv = (TextView) v; //code corrected
            TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
            tv.setText("My new text");
        }
});
```

TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);

Comment: I hope you know that this is totally wrong. The `v` parameter in the `onClick()` method is the clicked on view. Now if he clicks on a `Button` with your code all that happens is that the text of your `Button` changes.

Comment: Oh! Button and TextView are different. Yes its my mistake. I am going to delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the setText("anything") method.

Answer (score 0):

In `onclick`, take the object of the TextView and set the desired text like so:

```
tvOBJECT.setText("your text");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java only no XML version**

To make things more explicit:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    private int i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.i = 0;

        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(String.format("%d", this.i));

        final Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("click me");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Main.this.i++;
                tv.setText(String.format("%d", Main.this.i));
            }
        });

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.addView(button);
        linearLayout.addView(tv);
        this.setContentView(linearLayout);
    }
}
```

Tested on Android 22.