# Changing TextView text on button click (Android)

Tags: android

I am trying to change text of a textview on a button click. Below is the gist of my code but it doesnt seem to work. Am i doing something wrong. Thanks in Advance

```
//xml
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:text="blah blah blah"></TextView>
<Button android:text="Wrong answer." android:onClick="wrongAns" android:clickable="true"></Button>

//code
TextView theCorrectAnsTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

public void wrongAns(View v) 
{   
  theCorrectAnsTextView.setText("TextView text has changed!");
}
```

Comment: What is happening when you click the button?

Comment: From where is `wrongAns(View v)` function called? Please provide more details.

Comment: outside of  public class applicationName extends Activity.

Comment: code, seems fine, can you post the crash log?

Comment: your code is working just perfect

Comment: add log. hope its helpfull i tried my best to format it so its readable.

Comment: also note that im not using an onClickListener. The button just triggers the fuction. Could this be the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a TextView's text by pressing a Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716748/how-to-change-a-textviews-text-by-pressing-a-button)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. First you give onclick event for Button like (buttonClick).
2. In java file just write below code.

   ```
   public void buttonClick(View v)
   {
   TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   tv.setText("Welcome to android");
   }
   ```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to initialize the button.
And if it doesn't work, just do it in java code :

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(YourId);
btn.setonClickListener(listener);

public onClickListener listener = new View.OnclickListener{
      onclick(View v){
      // do your thing
      }
}
```

Something like that, i don't remember without eclipse to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple view with the background a textbox and a button you need to use

```
public void OnMyButtonClick (View v)
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.textVal);
    if (tv != null)
      {tv.setText("Hallo");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setContentView, please check [What is setContentView(R.layout.main)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706348/what-is-setcontentviewr-layout-main)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mStatusTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some explanation because code-only answers are discouraged and may, sometimes, be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin** To add an **OnClickListener** to a **Button** to change the **Text(value)** of a **TextView** You have to write the following code in the onCreate method of MainActivity

```
    var textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)        
    var button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        textView.setText("Imran Khan")
    })
```