# What is setContentView(R.layout.main)?

Tags: android, layout

I understand that it has to do with the App layout, but when do I have to use it?
I tried to look for a link that explained this method, but I couldn't find it.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 67):

In Android the visual design is stored in XML files and each [Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities) is associated to a design.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

`R` means Resource

`layout` means design

`main` is the xml you have created under `res->layout->main.xml`

Whenever you want to change the current look of an Activity or when you move from one Activity to another, the new Activity must have a design to show. We call [`setContentView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) in onCreate with the desired design as argument.

Comment: What does it do? How do we use it? Why are we forced to use it?

Comment: what if you do not call setContentView at all?

Comment: When building an Android app with C code (i.e. NDK), is there a C-language equivalent of `setContentView` and `R.layout.main`?

Answer (score 13):

As per the documentation :

> Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all    top-level views to the activity.

Your `Launcher` activity in the manifest first gets called and it set the layout view as specified in respective java files `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. Now this activity uses `setContentView(R.layout.main)` to set xml layout to that activity which will actually render as the UI of your activity.

Comment: This documentation comes from the version of `setContentView()` which takes a `View` parameter.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for correcting. Working for 16 hrs now need some sleep :)

Answer (score 10):

[Why setContentView() in Android Had Been So Popular Till Now?](https://androidride.com/what-setcontentview-android-studio/)

setContentView(int layoutid) - method of activity class. It shows layout on screen.

R.layout.main - is an integer number implemented in nested layout class of R.java class file.

At the run time device will pick up their layout based on the id given in setcontentview() method.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can set content view (or design) of an activity. For example you can do it like this too :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedinstanceState);

    Button testButon = new Button(this);

    setContentView(testButon);   
}
```

Also watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H92G3CpSQf4) tutorial too.

Answer (score 3):

**Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.**

- Activity is basically a empty window
- SetContentView is used to fill the window with the UI provided from
  layout file    incase of setContentView(R.layout.somae_file).
- Here layoutfile is inflated to view and added to the Activity context(Window).