# How to prevent my app from crashing?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am a newbie and trying to make an android application for Online Voting. I have just designed the layouts so far but, unfortunately, I am facing rendering problems and the null pointer exception.

When I open an activity from MainActivity, I can only see a white screen! The sequence of activities is as follows:

```
MainActivity --> Instructions or AdminLogin --> UserLogin or RegisterCandidate
```

Even after hours of googling, I am not able to figure out the exact problem. I have checked several answers on StackOverflow itself but failed to figure out what's wrong.

The error trace is as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.palakjain.onlinevotingschool/com.example.palakjain.onlinevotingschool.AdminLogin}: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at com.example.suniljain.onlinevotingschool.AdminLogin.onCreate(AdminLogin.java:39)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5141)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnConductVoting, btnInstructions, btnSkipInstructions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnConductVoting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConductVoting);
    btnInstructions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInstructions);
    btnSkipInstructions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSkipInstructions);

    btnConductVoting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminLogin.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btnInstructions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Instructions.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btnSkipInstructions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserLogin.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Instructions code:

```
public class Instructions extends AppCompatActivity{
Button btnStartVoting;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    btnStartVoting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartVoting);

    btnStartVoting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Instructions.this, UserLogin.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

AdminLogin code:

```
public class AdminLogin extends AppCompatActivity{

Button btnAdminLogin;
EditText etUsername;
EditText etPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    btnAdminLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdminLogin);
    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdminPassword);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdminPassword);

    btnAdminLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(etUsername.getText().toString().equals("administrator") && etPassword.getText().toString().equals("password")){
                Intent i = new Intent(AdminLogin.this, RegisterCandidate.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

UserLogin code:

```
public class UserLogin extends AppCompatActivity{

//TextView tvUserForgotPassword;
TextView tvNewUserSignUp;
//Button btnUserLogIn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    tvNewUserSignUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNewUserSignUp);        

    tvNewUserSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(UserLogin.this, NewUser.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
}
```

RegisterCandidate code:

```
public class RegisterCandidate extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

NewUser code:

```
public class NewUser extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

**Update1**: I have made all the changes that are suggested in the answers, still my application is crashing whenever I click "SKIP INSTRUCTIONS" button in the MainActivity. Also, app crashes when I click "Log-in" button from AdminLogin Activity. What should I do?

**Update2**: i referred [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) yet couldn't fix the error!

Comment: did you added you activities in manifest ?

Comment: @Palak Jain and You can't use `==` on java for check variable values , you must use `.equals` instead of `==`

Comment: yes, I have @SudheeshR

Comment: Thanks @Mahdi.Pishguy

Comment: @Palak Jain  all of your activities such as `Instructions` - `AdminLogin` `UserLogin` - `RegisterCandidate` don't have setContentView

Comment: No @Nilesh Rathod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't `setContentView` in `AdminLogin` Activity.

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // set contentview here before finding views otherwise they will be null
    btnAdminLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdminLogin);
   }
```

Just a note, same issue is with your other activities, cross check that.

If you want to know what is `setContentView` then in a short term it associate View/UI which will display when `Activity` launch. For an example - If you want to show `EditText` and `Button` on UI then they must be present in layout file which have .xml extension. (You can also create View through java code)

Comment: what's setContentView? Actually I am a newbie

Comment: in a setContentView you have to pass layout_id of your activity. Check your MainActivity there you wrote setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Comment: @PalakJain Use .equals to compare strings, not ==

Comment: yes, I have made all the changes...thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice, happy coding!

Comment: I have made all the changes that are suggested in the answer, still, my application is crashing whenever I click "SKIP INSTRUCTIONS" button in the MainActivity. Also, app crashes when I click "Log-in" button from AdminLogin Activity. What should I do?

Comment: Or can you cross check, you associate correct layout with UserLogin Activity and it is registered in manifest file

Comment: can we discuss the issue on mail?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare Strings with `==`  in your AdminLogin activity `etUsername.getText().toString() == "administrator"`

use

`etUsername.getText().toString().equals("administrator")`

also you didn't setContentView as stated in above answer

Answer (score 1):

as far as you are newbie on android you must read this documents to set `setContentView`

[What is setContentView(R.layout.main)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706348/what-is-setcontentviewr-layout-main)

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no back end and front end language for Android. Both are done using Java. The XML file is just a layout or skeleton for the activity. To use the activity one must use

```
setContentView(R.id.layout_id)
```