# Android; How to show up Button when doing a method

Tags: java, android

I'm totally beginner in Java and Android programming.

Now I wan to show up button when a method is run. But the button is already placed on the screen.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set the listener for the button
    mConfrimButtton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm_button);
}

public void aMethod {
    // show up the button when doing this method but the button is already shown up
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First Issue

You forgot to call **`setContentView(R.layout.layout);`**

Read more here [What is setContentView(R.layout.main)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706348/what-is-setcontentviewr-layout-main)

- Now I wan to show up button when a method is run

You can use [**`setVisibility`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

> Set the visibility state of this view.
>   EX. **`mConfrimButtton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`**

- But the button is already placed on the screen.

You can use [**`android:visibility`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:visibility)

> Controls the initial visibility of the view. 
>   EX. **`android:visibility="gone"`**

You can read more here about [Android : difference between invisible and gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone/23211042#23211042)

Comment: Thanks. It works but it works without `setContentView()`. I still don't understand what the first issue is.

Comment: @ani  r u sure you code works without `setContentView()` because there no `setContentView()` method in your above code inside `onCreate()` method

Comment: @ani check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

When the activity loads, set its visibility to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE` in your layout XML:

```
<Button android:text="Your Button"
    android:id="@+id/yourButton"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Then, in your Java activity code, make that button visible:

```
mConfirmButtton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
mConfirmButtom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Note that adding an OnClick listener is not directly related to what you described in your question.  A click listener is what would fire if the button, already visible, were clicked by a user in that activity.  But, it wouldn't have anything to do with making that button visible when a certain method is run.

Comment: id in XML and JAVA should be same, please fix it

Answer (score 0):

Write `mConfrimButtton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` in `onCreate()`
And then make button visible in `aMethod()` by using `mConfrimButtton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

Answer (score 0):

make button visibility gone

in xml:-

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

you can also set button visibility programatically

```
mConfrimButtton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

wherever you want to show button set button visibility VISIBLE

```
mConfrimButtton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```