# FATAL EXCEPTION: main (android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run an app using Android Studio 3.4.1, but the application crashes when I try to debug or run it.

I've encountered the `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo` error once already, but on a project that used Kotlin (this project is using Java), and with a different exception. I've tried editing the manifest, modifying activities and changing all of the images in the `mipmap` folders to the `drawable` folders, but none of that worked.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.testapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_notifications" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_dashboard" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.testapp.DashboardActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".BaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My `BaseActivity.java`:

```java
package com.example.testapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected BottomNavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getContentViewId()); //References this line in the logs

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updateNavigationBarState();
    }

    // Remove inter-activity transition to avoid screen tossing on tapping bottom navigation items
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull final MenuItem item) {
        navigationView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int itemId = item.getItemId();
                if (itemId == R.id.navigation_home) {
                    BaseActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, BaseActivity.class));
                } else if (itemId == R.id.navigation_dashboard) {
                    BaseActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class));
                } else if (itemId == R.id.navigation_notifications) {
                    BaseActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, NotificationsActivity.class));
                }
                BaseActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 300);
        return true;
    }

    private void updateNavigationBarState(){
        int actionId = getNavigationMenuItemId();
        selectBottomNavigationBarItem(actionId);
    }

    void selectBottomNavigationBarItem(int itemId) {
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        for (int i = 0, size = menu.size(); i < size; i++) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            boolean shouldBeChecked = item.getItemId() == itemId;
            if (shouldBeChecked) {
                item.setChecked(true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int getContentViewId() {
        return 0;
    }

    int getNavigationMenuItemId() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

And my debugging log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 10261
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.BaseActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2827)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2902)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1603)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6578)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:204)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2133)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1142)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.testapp.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7016)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2902) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1603) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6578) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The app was supposed to work, but after modifying the .javas, it started giving this error no matter what I did. I've seen some questions that had similar results, but none of them actually helped me.

Comment: The cause of the error is specified in your LogCat: at com.example.testapp.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:18). This corresponds to your code setConentView(getContentViewId()). The getContentViewId() function always returns 0. Read up more on setConentView() here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706348/what-is-setcontentviewr-layout-main.

Comment: Try changing `setContentView(getContentViewId());` to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);`

Comment: @HB. Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

`setContentView(getContentViewId());`

to

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);`

---

The error :

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

means that the resource can't be found and since it is pointing to `setContentView`, it means that `getContentViewId()` could not be found.