# reading and displaying data from text file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn how to create apps and got stuck at the very beginning.  I read lots of topics about this issue and still couldn't manage to find out how to do this. I think I got the reading from text file part right but don't know how to display it. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/Eothen/AndroidStudioProjects/FutbolBorsasi/app/src/main/res/infobank.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("line");
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/nameTextView"
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ppImageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundtextview"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

strings.xml

```
 <string name="nameTextView">DISPLAY HERE</string>
```

infobank.txt

```
READ HERE
```

Edit: This Worked

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String line;
TextView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = am.open("test.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        line = reader.readLine();
        view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        view.setText(line);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line = reader.readLine();
System.out.println("line");
```

You should display it in TextView, not console.

Like:

```
TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
view.setText(line);
```

And `System.out.println("line");` will display "line", not text of that file, you must remove " ".

**EDIT:** dont forget to change `R.id.counter` to `R.id.<id of your textview>`

**Edit2:**

Try this:

```
public void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/Eothen/AndroidStudioProjects/FutbolBorsasi/app/src/main/res/infobank.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        line = reader.readLine();
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        view.setText(line);
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

How do you want to read file which is on C drive from emulator?
Try [Reading a simple text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771366/reading-a-simple-text-file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716748/how-to-change-a-textviews-text-by-pressing-a-button - there is more info abut it.

Comment: Place your text file in the /assets directory under the Android project. Use AssetManager class to access it.

`AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("test.txt");`
Or you can also put the file in the /res/raw directory, where the file will be indexed and is accessible by an id in the R file:

`InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);`


Credits to @shihpeng http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771366/reading-a-simple-text-file

Comment: If you need to read file from external place (internal storage, not app) try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors here. The first one is that in android there isn't `public void main(String[] args)` but instead you have to declare in your manifest what is your main activity and override the `onCreate`, `onStart`, etc. methods provided by the `Activity` class. Second, the filesystem of an android device (or android emulator) is different from your pc filesystem, then `C:/Users/Eothen/AndroidStudioProjects/FutbolBorsasi/app/src/main/res/infobank.txt` is wrong.

I suggest you to start reading some tutorial first (there are many available online), and then try again.